# How to forward protocol methods to existing type?

Tags: clojure, protocols, record

How can I define a new record that "inherits" the protocols from an existing type?

To make this question clear, I'll illustrate with extending [Ubergraph](https://github.com/Engelberg/ubergraph), but Ubergraph is only an example; I'm looking for the general solution, not just a solution that works for Ubergraph. Suppose that I'd like to add a global attribute, `graph-name`, to Ubergraph. Ideally, I could do something like this:

```
(defrecord named-ubergraph [g graph-name])

(extend-type named-ubergraph
  (all-the-protocols-supported-by ubergraph.core.Ubergraph)
  (call-the-same-functions-replacing-first-argument-with '(this g))
```

Of course I could look at the Ubergraph source code and manually write all the forwarding functions, but [as you can see here](https://github.com/Engelberg/ubergraph/blob/320e284a6de6adb241df5dfeb9fd6383caea659c/src/ubergraph/core.clj#L121), Ubergraph satisfies *many* protocols and *many* protocol methods.

Writing so much boilerplate code doesn't sound very Clojurely, and it seems like a lot of work when all I want to do is add one eensy-weensy bit of data to an Ubergraph. What's a better way?

Please feel free to reconceptualize the question if you think I'm looking at this wrong.

Answer (score 1):

`extend-type` extends existing types to given protocols.
If I understand you properly, you want to extend existing record to achieve some kind of inheritance.
AFAIK, there's no easy way to do this.
However, if all you want is to add another field, you can easily `assoc` additional field to an existing record instance:

```
(defprotocol Cost
  (cost [this price-list]))

(defrecord Car [name speed]
  Cost
  (cost [this price-list] (price-list (:name this))))

(def my-car (->Car "bmw" 200))
(def price-list {"bmw" 100000})

(cost my-car price-list)
;;=> 100000

(-> my-car
    (assoc :color "blue")
    (cost price-list))
;;=> 100000
```

UPDATE:
I've also found this fantastic discussion on Clojure mailing list: defrecord with "inheritance": https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/mr-o9sRyiZ0

Comment: Just `assoc`-ing to the record is a good insight! I knew that Clojure allowed this, but I hadn't thought of it in connection with this problem. This instantly solves many of my current problems—with the ideal amount of code: none! However, I just tried `assoc`-ing to an Ubergraph, and that doesn't work. So, I'm leaving the question open for now. (Adding arbitrary data to an Ubergraph _is_ actually the main practical reason that I need this right now.)

Comment: Hmm, Ubergraph even has [case statements](https://github.com/Engelberg/ubergraph/blob/320e284a6de6adb241df5dfeb9fd6383caea659c/src/ubergraph/core.clj#L214) that prevent `assoc`-ing to arbitrary keys.